# How do I get a specific scale/zoom level in the QGIS canvas?

Tags: qgis, zoom, scale-factor

I have a map project with CRS = NAD83 zone 13N. The canvas will zoom to 1:144,447, 1:288,295, 1:577,790, etc. The values in the dropdown, on the other hand are 1:100,000, 1:250,000, 1:500,000, etc. Why is it zooming to these odd values and how do I coerce it to zoom to the levels in the dropdown or typed into the scale box?

QGIS 2.12.1 - Lyon
Win 7 Pro 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS usually zooms to the layer extent after loading. By using the mousewheel, you can then zoom by a factor of 2. Selecting a different value in the scale dropdownbox will change the current value.

If you have installed the `Tile Map Scales` plugin, scales will be set to an optimal view for EPSG:3857 based tile servers, like OpenStreetMap or Google.
in the `options` tab of the plugin, you can uncheck `Use World Mercator System` to get free scale levels back.

Comment: The issue was indeed the Tile Map Scales plug-in, which I had forgotten I had installed.